# What could be the cause of these spikes in current when measuring it from a solar panel

Tags: photovoltaics

I was measuring the current through a solar panel at different light intensities and I found that sometimes it caused large spikes in the current and I can't find a reason for this phenomenon. Is this a problem with my solar panel/measuring device or is it due to a property of solar panels?[image]

Comment: how could load change? What was effect on voltage?

Comment: what was the light intensity at the time that the spikes occured?

Comment: these spikes were seen in all light intensities but were seen frequently when light intensity increased

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 there wasn't major fluctuation in voltage

Comment: The load causes the current, not the source which is undefined...

Comment: I can't answer your question until you describe the entire circuit.